# Roots of convex combination of two polynomials with real coefficient

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots

Suppose we have two monic polynomials $p_1(x), p_2(x)$ with real coefficients of the same degree. If the roots of both polynomials are in the disk $D = \{ z \in \mathbb C : |z| < R\}$. Let $p_t(x) = (1-t) p_1(x) + t p_2(x)$ where $t \in [0,1]$. What can we say about the roots of $p_t(x)$? Will the roots be in the disk $D$?

Comment: For $p_1(x)=x-1$ and $p_2(x)=-x-1$ you get that $p_t(x)=(2t-1)x-1$. The root of $p_t$ is at $x=\frac{1}{2t-1}$, which can be as large as you want, or no root at all when $t=1/2$.

Comment: @totoro: note that the polynomials have to be monic.

Comment: See H.J. Fell's [On the zeros of convex combinations of polynomials](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102779366#ui-tabs-1).